# (HTML frame tag) target frame won't work again after clicked

Tags: html, anchor, frame, target, frameset

we were tasked to create a web program as quiz that will perform as a pdf page navigator using frameset and frame tag , my problem is that after i clicked on an anchor tag, if i clicked on anchor tag again the targeted frame won't show or prompt again.

how can i make other anchor tag clickable and prompt to targeted frame again after i clicked on an anchor tag? its hard to find about frame since its obsolete.

here is my code:

frame

```
<frameset rows="20%,70%,10%" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frameset cols="20%,80%" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame name="logo" src="logo.html" noresize="noresize">
        <frame name="banner" src="banner.html">
    </frameset>
<frameset cols="20%,80%" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="menu" src="menu.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
    <frame name="content" src="content.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
</frameset>

  <frame name="footer" src="footer.html" scrolling="no">
```

pdf page navigator

```
<a href="tr_css.pdf#page=1" target = "content" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-sm text-black" aria-current="true">
<a href="tr_css.pdf#page=2" target = "content" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-sm text-black" aria-current="true">
<a href="tr_css.pdf#page=3" target = "content" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-sm text-black" aria-current="true">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a programmers perspective this is a nightmare of 3rd party dependencies, and emulations.

I do not think it matters if frame or iframe, I had the same problem with Edge iframes. Will it work  with Mac Safari, Microsoft Edge, Android Chrome :-) or cross platform Mozilla FireFox / Acrobat based PDF plug-ins?

And the answer is it should work with FireFox since PDF.js is not a conventional PDF viewer.

However although designed by Acrobat for use via ActiveX in MS Trident those `#page=#` may not work the same way with Acrobat imbedded in more recently secured Chrome or Edge.

Here in Firefox without Acrobat, I have been through Page 1 then 2 then 3 no problem.

[image]

Now a related issue with Edge (and possibly others) is each time you load a PDF, a user default preference may be set to always open same page.

When using Edge there is a user over-ride. which for testing, needs to be switched off by the user, whereby reloading a PDF will always show the same page.

However switching that off (shown as part of top right of this image) still does not help with Chromium based PDF viewers.

[image]

So what is needed to reload each page in turn for Chrome is presumably the same as used here for Edge where I can "Navigate" by reload /download whole file as pages in any order like 1 2 3.
[image]

That answer was provided by Yu Zhou (https://stackoverflow.com/users/11490347/yu-zhou) when I asked for any similar  workarounds to the Chrome cache locking of the current file.

So try this as your Menu.html

```
<a href="tr_css.pdf?=1#page=1" target = "content" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-sm text-black" aria-current="true">page 1</a><br>
<a href="tr_css.pdf?=2#page=2" target = "content" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-sm text-black" aria-current="true">page 2</a><br>
<a href="tr_css.pdf?=3#page=3" target = "content" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-sm text-black" aria-current="true">page 3</a><br>
```

Comment: thanks sir, this solved my problem, recently I tried using javascript but none of those are working, but this one works perfectly, I really appreciate